# jQuery and HTML loaded via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to grab a child element of HTML loaded dynamically via AJAX. It is not working.

```
 $.get('test.html', function(data) {

    var content = $('#content', data).html();

    console.log(content); // Logs "Null"

    $('#result').html(content);

  });
```

Here is the 'test.html'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Website</title>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" value="" />
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Hello!!!</h1>

  <div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam feugiat tincidunt tortor eu iaculis. Sed id urna sem, quis malesuada lacus. Nulla iaculis malesuada libero, id vehicula sapien imperdiet eu.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, if I try this: `console.log($(data));`, Firebug gives me this:

```
[<TextNode textContent="\n\n\n ">, meta, <TextNode textContent="\n ">, title, <TextNode textContent="\n ">, meta, <TextNode textContent="\n ">, meta, <TextNode textContent="\n\n\n \n ">, h1, <TextNode textContent="\n \n ">, div#content, <TextNode textContent="\n\n\n\n">]
```

Any ideas???

Comment: where is the #content in the html file ?

Comment: Sorry... #holder was meant to be #content. I fixed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake with the content var i believe, it doesnt make sense.

```
 $.get('test.html #content', function(data) {
 console.log(data); // Logs "Null"
 $('#result').html(data);
 });
```

thats how jquery website would say to do it.

I say use

```
$('#result').load('test.html #content');
```

hows that for ya?

Answer (score 0):

try using $.ajax instead:

```
 $.ajax({
   url:'test.html', 
   dataType:'html',
   success:function(data) {
    var content = $('#content', data).html();
    console.log(content); // Logs "Null"
    $('#result').html(content);
   }
  });
```

Comment: Yeah, it gives me the same results too.

Comment: Correct.  I wanted to be able to identify the name of the parameters though. The main point being to identify the dataType in case jQuery is not properly determining the data type from the MIME type in the response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to do, but I'm assuming you want to get the contents of `#content` in your `test.html` page and inject that into your `#results` div.

```
$.get('test.html', function(data) {
    var content = $(data).find("#content").html();
    $('#result').html(content);
});
```

Comment: Sorry... #holder was meant to be #content. I fixed above. Anyway, I tried your suggestion, and `content` still logs out as `null`.

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(data)` in the callback?

Comment: It looks as you'd expect... the contents of the file.